# How to play video till one point and move to another frame in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video-reactjs

I have a React project where I'm having a slider between 0 and 700 and depending on which step is chosen it gets value between `1` and `8` (so 700 is obviously 8).

```
 <div className={styles.slider_container}>
                    <input type='range' className={styles.slider} step={100} min={0} max={700} value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(parseInt(e.target.value))} />
                </div>
```

I also have an `frames` array which consists of bunch of objects which look like:

```
    const [frames, setFrames] = useState([
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Touch',
            start: 0,
            idle: 5.82,
            end: 7.10,
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Display',
            start: 7.11,
            idle: 8.5,
            end: 10.12,
        },
        ...
    ];
```

and I call my `VideoPlayer` component as:

```
<div className={styles.content}>
                <VideoPlayer frames={frames} currentComponent={selectedComponent} prevComponent={prevComponent} startTime={frames.find((item) => item.id === selectedComponent).start} endTime={frames.find((item) => item.id === selectedComponent).end} idleTime={frames.find((item) => item.id === selectedComponent).idle} />
            </div>
```

`VideoPlayer` component is just using [react-video](https://video-react.js.org/components/player/) library to display the video and play/pause/seek through it. and it is just like:

```
 const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(startTime);
    const playerRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (currentTime >= idleTime) {
            playerRef.current.pause();
        }
    }, [currentTime]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (prevComponent) {

            if (prevComponent < currentComponent) {
                const time = (frames.find(item => item.id === prevComponent).end); // endTime of previous component;
                if (currentTime <= time) {
                    playerRef.current.play();
                    if (time - currentTime <= 0.3) {
                        playerRef.current.pause();
                        playerRef.current.seek(startTime);
                        playerRef.current.play();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, [currentTime, currentComponent]);


    useEffect(() => {
        if (prevComponent > currentComponent) {
            playerRef.current.seek(startTime);
            playerRef.current.play();
        }
    }, [currentComponent]);

    return (
        <Player
            ref={playerRef}
            autoPlay
            startTime={0}
            muted={true}
            onTimeUpdate={(e) => {
                setCurrentTime(parseFloat(e.target.currentTime));
            }}
        >
            <source src="./video.mp4" style={{ height: '100vh' }} />
            <ControlBar autoHide={false} disableCompletely={true} disableDefaultControls={true} />
        </Player>
```

It works fine with going forward (I mean from step 2 to step 3 or step 4), but I have a problem in

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (prevComponent > currentComponent) {
            playerRef.current.seek(startTime);
            playerRef.current.play();
        }
    }, [currentComponent]);
```

where if I select a component (or step) 2 after step 3 (if we go back), it should play the video till endTime of the `prevComponent` and then just back to `startTime` of `currentComponent` and continue playing till `idleTime` of the `currentComponent`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would apply the `while` loop to `if (prevComponent > currentComponent)` condition, so it would just play the video till the difference between `time` and `currentTime` is less or equal to zero, if so, just break out from the loop and then use `seek()` function to jump to another frame/time you want.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (prevComponent > currentComponent) {
            while(time - currentTime > 0) {
                playerRef.current.play();
            }
            playerRef.current.seek(startTime);
        }
    }, [currentTime, currentComponent]);
```

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the behavior you described where the video should play from the end of the previous component to the start of the current component when moving backward, you can make some modifications to your `VideoPlayer` component. Specifically, you need to update the logic in the `useEffect` that handles moving from a higher component to a lower one.

You can do this by calculating the time to play from the end of the previous component to the start of the current component and then continue playing from there. Here's the modified code:

```js
const VideoPlayer = ({ frames, currentComponent, prevComponent, startTime, endTime, idleTime }) => {
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(startTime);
  const playerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentTime >= idleTime) {
      playerRef.current.pause();
    }
  }, [currentTime]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (prevComponent && prevComponent > currentComponent) {
      // Calculate the time to play from the end of the previous component to the start of the current component.
      const previousEnd = frames.find((item) => item.id === prevComponent).end;
      const currentStart = startTime;
      const timeToPlay = currentStart - previousEnd;

      // Play from the calculated time.
      if (timeToPlay > 0) {
        playerRef.current.play();
        playerRef.current.seek(previousEnd);
        setTimeout(() => {
          playerRef.current.pause();
          playerRef.current.seek(currentStart);
          playerRef.current.play();
        }, timeToPlay * 1000);
      }
    }
  }, [currentTime, currentComponent, prevComponent, frames, startTime]);

  return (
    <Player
      ref={playerRef}
      autoPlay
      startTime={0}
      muted={true}
      onTimeUpdate={(e) => {
        setCurrentTime(parseFloat(e.target.currentTime));
      }}
    >
      <source src="./video.mp4" style={{ height: '100vh' }} />
      <ControlBar autoHide={false} disableCompletely={true} disableDefaultControls={true} />
    </Player>
  );
};
```

Comment: It does not play the video at all if I click to next component.